# Bootstrap под разные разрешения

Tags: html, css, вёрстка, bootstrap

Можно ли под разные разрешения использовать свойства bootstrap?чтобы к примеру к одному и тому же объекту было применено свойство одного типа, но под разные разрешения.подскажите пожалуйста

Answer (score -1):

В документации bootstrap говорится о контрольных точках [контрольных точках](https://getbootstrap.su/docs/5.2/layout/breakpoints/).
С помощью них можно делать макет, который будет изменяться в зависимости от ширины

Comment: Ссылаться на внешний материал конечно хорошо, но также нужно оставлять цитаты (и код если имеется) из ссылок, чтобы пользователи понимали что из ждёт из ссылки, а также это будет полезно если доступ к ресурсу был потерян. Подробнее [в справке](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/referencing).